# Объединение данных в группы

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Есть задача объединить данные в группы.
Имею к примеру словарь в котором 100 списков в таком виде:

```
dict_ = {'kukuruza':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'sahar':[2,3,4,5,6,7], 'svekla':[1,0,0,0,0,0]}
```

Так вот имеем словарь `{'kukuruza':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'sahar':[2,3,4,5,6,7], 'svekla':[1,0,0,0,0,0]}`. На выходе я хочу получить словарь, который будет иметь минимум 3 пересечения в значениях. В моем примере я должен получить: `{1:['kukuruza', 'sahar'], 2:['svekla']}`. Так как у ключа kukuruza и sahar есть 3 одинаковых значения 2,3,4 мы их объединяем в одну группу, а свекла не имеет пересечений.

Как мне объединить в одну группу списки, где пересечений больше 3х?
Пока в мыслях использовать матрицу, может есть еще какие-то способы?

Comment: Покажите ожидаемый результат, на словах непонятно

Comment: в текущей формулировке непонятно что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: Прошу прощения, писал в транспорте, интернет отвалился.
Так вот имеем словарь {'kukuruza':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'sahar':[2,3,4,5,6,7], 'svekla':[1,0,0,0,0,0]}
На выходе я хочу получить словарь, который будет иметь минимум 3 пересечения в значениях. В моем примере я должен получить:
{1:['kukuruza', 'sahar'], 2:['svekla'] . Так как у ключа kukuruza и sahar есть 3 одинаковых значения 2,3,4 мы их объединяем в одну группу, а свекла не имеет пересечений.

Comment: @sanitarn добавьте ваше дополнение в вопрос, чтобы его могли переоткрыть и дать на него ответ.

Comment: Так я вроде его сразу добавил, разве нет?

Answer (score 1):

```
dict_ = {'kukuruza':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'sahar':[2,3,4,5,6,7], 'svekla':[1,0,0,0,0,0]} 
rez = {}
key_rez = 1

for k1, v1 in dict_.items():
    iist_ = [k1,]
    for k2, v3 in dict_.items():
        if k1 != k2:
            len_ = len(set(dict_[k1]) & set(dict_[k2]))
            if len_ > 2:
                iist_.append(k2)
    w_list = sorted(iist_)
    fl = True
    for v in rez.values():
        if v == w_list:
            fl = False
    if fl:
        rez[key_rez] = sorted(iist_)
        key_rez += 1

print(rez)
{1: ['kukuruza', 'sahar'], 2: ['svekla']}
```

---

**Update**

```
dict_ = {'kukuruza':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 
         'sahar':[2,3,4,5,6,7], 
         'svekla':[1,0,0,0,0,0], 
         'proso':[5,6,7,13,14,15],
         'fasol':[1,0,3,0,5,0],}

list_all = []
k1, v1 = list(dict_.keys())[0], dict_[list(dict_.keys())[0]]
iist_ = [k1,]

for k2, v2 in dict_.items():
    if k1 != k2:
        len_ = len(set(dict_[k1]) & set(dict_[k2]))
        if len_ > 2:
            iist_.append(k2)
        else:
            list_all.append(k2)

list_all.insert(0, iist_)
rez = [ {k:v} for k, v in enumerate(list_all) ]

print(rez)

#[{0: ['kukuruza', 'sahar', 'fasol']}, {1: 'svekla'}, {2: 'proso'}]
```

Comment: dict_ = {'kukuruza':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'sahar':[2,3,4,5,6,7], 'svekla':[1,0,0,0,0,0], 'proso':[5,6,7,13,14,15]} ?

Comment: @strawdog  `{1: ['kukuruza', 'sahar'], 2: ['kukuruza', 'proso', 'sahar'], 3: ['svekla'], 4: ['proso', 'sahar']}`  Почему `2: ['kukuruza', 'proso', 'sahar'],` ? Т.к. 'sahar' имеет больше 2-х совпадений с 'kukuruza' и больше 2-х совпадений с  'proso'.

Comment: Почему - понятно, но, возможно, группы 1 и 4 избыточны?

Comment: @strawdog пусть автор вопроса что-то скажет. В вопросе написано `хочу получить словарь, который будет иметь минимум 3 пересечения в значениях.`

Comment: @S.Nick спасибо ща решение, но видимо проблема в том, что я не доконца объяснил алгоритм. Берем словарь
dict_ = {'kukuruza':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'sahar':[2,3,4,5,6,7], 'svekla':[1,0,0,0,0,0], 'proso':[5,6,7,13,14,15]}

Нам нужно собрать группы по правилу, если есть больше 3х совпадений, то группа формируется.
В нашем случаем, мы берем первый ключ kukuruza и его значения и ищем совпадения в других ключах,
если есть совпадения, то мы этот ключ и значение переносим в новую группу, таким образом у нас будет:
[kukuruza, sahar] , proso не должно попасть так как он не совместим с kukuruza.

Comment: Нашел ссылку на сам алгоритм кластеризации https://www.searchengines.ru/azbuka_klasterizats.html метод hard , нужно что-то такое.

Comment: @sanitarn а так, смотрите обновление.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools

def get(dt, p_min=3):
    """На выходе я хочу получить словарь, который будет иметь минимум 3 пересечения в значениях."""
    r = {}
    for (n1, n2) in itertools.combinations(dt, 2):
        own = (set(dt[n1]) & set(dt[n2]))
        if len(own) >= p_min:
            own = tuple(own)
            try:
                r[own].add(n1)
                r[own].add(n2)
            except:
                r[own] = {n1, n2}
        continue
    return r

dict_ = {'kukuruza':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'sahar':[2,3,4,5,6,7, 8, 9], 'svekla':[1,0,0,0,0,0], 'qwe':[1,7, 8, 9,0,0]}
r = get(dict_)
print(r)  # {(2, 3, 4, 5, 6): {'kukuruza', 'sahar'}, (8, 9, 7): {'qwe', 'sahar'}}
```